# Amazon AWS simple book query. How do you make Signature in Delphi?

Tags: amazon-web-services, delphi, signature

There are an awful lot of question on stackoverflow that bear some similarity to this question, but nothing quite like it.

I have an application that makes queries of AWS and sends back XML data. I have monitoried it and it sends a string like this one:

http://ecs.amazonaws.com/onca/xml?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAID6DSLQQRYN3MDQA&AssociateTag=wwwratterriec-20&Keywords=031238792X&Operation=ItemSearch&SearchIndex=Books&Service=AWSECommerceService&SignatureMethod=HmacSHA1&SignatureVersion=2&Timestamp=2013-04-30T22%3A00%3A00.000Z&Version=2011-08-01&Signature=n1x%2BtbR71WFAgPHYq4rrpamgMb4%3D

If you try it, you will get some XML that tells you "Request has expired. Timestamp date is 2013-04-30T22:00:00.000Z" etc.

If the "ToBeSigned" does not match, you get the message "The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided."

My problem is that I cannot get a version of the "ToBeSigned" that generates the correct "Signature". I find the documentation confusing - perhaps because it is geared to Java or PHP.

What is the correct "ToBeSigned" in the above link? **In Delphi pseudocode please!**

Comment: I believe the signature has something to do with **Timestamp** parameter in the URL, so you might look into that.

Comment: Yes, it is all "explained" here:

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely correct. It is all "explained" here:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/rest-signature.html

However, when I code it, I cannot get it to work. I am wondering if someone can be so kind as to provide a code snippet. I have Googled all over and can't find anything that works in Delphi

Comment: look at step 8 and at the "unsigned" and "signed" examples, try to "sign" the "unsigned" and see if it matches, only then you can move forward, also, the link should be included in the question. For encryption and hashing, look at http://www.cityinthesky.co.uk/opensource/dcpcrypt, have fun!

Comment: You keep putting *explained* in scare quotes to indicate you don't really believe that document explains anything. I've just read it, and it seems clear as day. Which part are you having trouble with? It doesn't appear to be geared toward any programming language at all. Everything described is ordinary computational operations: sorting by byte value, replacing some ASCII characters with other ASCII characters, computing SHA256 hash, etc. It even includes multiple examples. Are you sure you're using the right secret key?

Comment: Rob, I make no pretences to being especially smart. Frankly, the AWS documentation is intimidating. I found one supplier who sells components for handling this stuff for $599 a shot so I guess I am not the only one who has problems:
http://www.nsoftware.com/ibiz/amazon/

Answer (score 2):

Here is the Delphi code that worked for me. Just change the value of parameters to suit your purposes and put in your own secret key. I put the TimeStamp at Now plus 2.4 hours - change it to suit your own purposes.

```
procedure TForm1.ButtonWorksClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  toHash, SecretAccessKey, dirstr, awssignature, sg, ts, link: String;
  sig: T160BitDigest;
  SystemTime1: SYSTEMTIME;
  dt1: TDateTime;
begin
  GetSystemTime(SystemTime1);
  dt1 := SystemTimeToDateTime(SystemTime1) + 0.1;
  ts := '&Timestamp=' + HTTPEncode(FormatDateTime('yyyy"-"mm"-"dd"T"hh":00:00.000Z', dt1));

  tohash := 'GET' + Chr(10) + 'ecs.amazonaws.com' + Chr(10) + '/onca/xml' + Chr(10) +
    'AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAID6DSLQQRYN3MDQA&AssociateTag=locboo01-20&Keywords=031238792X&Operation=ItemSearch&SearchIndex=Books' +
    '&Service=AWSECommerceService&SignatureMethod=HmacSHA1&SignatureVersion=2' + ts + '&Version=2011-08-01';

  SecretAccessKey := 'Your secret key here';

  Sig := cHash.CalcHMAC_SHA1(SecretAccessKey, tohash);
  dirstr := cHash.SHA1DigestAsString(Sig);
  awssignature := EncdDecd.EncodeString(dirstr);

  sg := HTTPApp.HTTPEncode(awssignature);
  link := 'http://ecs.amazonaws.com/onca/xml' + '?' +
    'AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAID6DSLQQRYN3MDQA&AssociateTag=locboo01-20&Keywords=031238792X&Operation=ItemSearch&SearchIndex=Books' +
    '&Service=AWSECommerceService&SignatureMethod=HmacSHA1&SignatureVersion=2' + ts + '&Version=2011-08-01' + '&Signature=' + sg;
  Clipboard.AsText := link;

  Memo1.Lines.Add(sg);
end;
```

Comment: What libs are you using? My Delphi can't find T160BitDigest, HTTPEncode, cHash and HTTPApp @user1355041